# php continue repeat foreach when last element

Tags: php, arrays, foreach

I have code to bring live ts files for client

I have folder that include dynamic files

```
/files
1_0.ts
1_1.ts
1_2.ts
```

My code brings files to client with that code

```
$files = "";
    $files = glob('/files/1_*.ts');
    foreach ($files as $file) {
    readfile($file);
}
```

Code get all files and send them to client and everything is ok

I need that client continue read files again when arrive to last element every time until he close browser

more explain

```
client get
1_0.ts
1_1.ts
1_2.ts
and watch them , I need client to read them again when he at the last file
1_0.ts
1_1.ts
1_2.ts

1_0.ts
1_1.ts
1_2.ts

1_0.ts
1_1.ts
1_2.ts

etc ..... until client close by itself
```

Comment: use your code segment inside while loop that always true. while(true){ your code segment}

Comment: can you give me example please

Answer (score 0):

You can use something like:

```
while (!connection_aborted()) {

    // here goes Your code that reads the files
    foreach (glob('/files/1_*.ts') as $file)
        readfile($file);

    // some waiting may be useful here?
    sleep(1);
}
```