# php update array every 2 seconds

Tags: php, arrays, file

I have folder with dynamic files, every 2 seconds there may be a new file.
I want check every 2 seconds if there are any new files or not.
If there are new files, add them to array.

Every file size about 1m.

I get files then start reading -- file after file.
I need to update array when reading files and continue reading and updating until the browser is closed.

I use this code:

```
if ($files = glob('/files/'.$video_id.'*.ts')) {
    $files = array_slice($files, -6, 6, true);
    foreach ($files as &$file) {
        if (!file_exists($file)) {
            unset($files[$file]);
            asort($files);
            reset($files);
        }
        $fp = @fopen($file, "r");
        echo fread($fp, filesize($file));
        $newfiles = glob('/files/'.video_id.'*.ts');
        $newfiles = array_slice($newfiles, -6, 6, true);
        foreach ($newfiles as &$newfile) {
            if (!in_array($newfile, $files, true)) {
                array_push($files, $newfile);
                asort($files);
                reset($files);
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: What is the qyestion?

Comment: You want to read and parse and process _all_ files, all of MB size, all every two seconds?

Comment: I need to update array when browser reading files and  updating as long as browser close

Comment: isn't what you posted earlier similar/the same? http://stackoverflow.com/q/42717575/1415724

Comment: i need every 2 seconds run this code to update array $newfiles = array_slice($newfiles, -6, 6, true);
                foreach ($newfiles as &$newfile) {
                    if(!in_array($newfile, $files, true)){
                    array_push($files, $newfile);
                    asort($files);
                    reset($files);
                    }
                }

Comment: no its not the same

Comment: Use sessions to store the old files that has been procesed

Comment: Sorting the array within the loop is meaningless, the loop operates on a copy of the array. Use an array iterator if you want this to work as you expect it.

Comment: @espooo , read Carefully the comment down bellow : [click here](http://stackoverflow.com/a/42752568/7465452) ......

Answer (score 0, accepted):

first you have to understand that php strings cannot be refreshed inside php itself when the string stored in Server memory .in some cases you can use in the top of your php script :

```
header('Refresh: 2');
```

**but !** that's gonna refresh your entire page even if you include it from other file. or you put it in a specific place. `header()` is made to reload or redirect the entire page.

> ***☼ Solution :*** to avoid refreshing the entire page use ( Ajax ). 
>  Example :

[image: Example image]

---

---

✔ -   **to call your (`php script`) using (`Ajax`) :**
        <sup>......................................................................................................................</sup>

- **1 -** creat a **New php File** inside your script directory 
       and name it Example : ( body.php )
  then add your (php code you want to reload) inside it

---

- **2 -** now in you index page add this :

  ```
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
  ```

then the simplest way to load the page we just created (body.php) is (JQuery load):

```
    <script type="text/javascript">
      setInterval(function(){ 
           $('#Request').load('Request.php'); 
      },  2000);

    </script>
```

then add this to your html area (where you want your code to show up) :

```
    <div id="Request"> your html video container here </div>
```

> read this article for more in-depth : https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ajax_(programming)

i saw that you trying to call some video links so change :
         `> your html video container here <` to feet your project.
         the important thing that you understand the general idea .

 other ways we can't do your whole home-work for you.
the few things that's need to be changed to feet your script is your job .

> ☼ **Note :**    the "**2000**" value we used in (javascript) is time by millisecond which = 2 sec you can change it next time if you want to add more time or less time . and remember ( 1000= 1 sec ) and base on that do the rest math by yourself , enjoy.